# Looking for Spanish material

Tags: vocabulario

I'm looking for a book or webpage which has a list of Spanish words and the sound of each word on the list. Can anyone help me?

Comment: To learn how Spanish is pronounced you only have to follow a few basic rules, as every word is pronounced the same way it is written. It's not the same as English where you have _speak_ and _steak_, quite similar but different in their pronunciations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are Japanese, as your name implies, you could try searching スペイン語の発音 in Google. [The first result](http://www.rondely.com/esp/first/pron.htm) seems pretty nice.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I decided to purchase a book with Spanish flashcards and mp3 audio files.